# Input id (autocompletion) with js does'nt work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would where is my error, inside this js because it does'nt work and the console I don't see nothing about the result input autocompletion for example
If you need more informations, tell me, I will add.

Thank you

Html result version
note :specification_row is an increment and when you add a new row inside the table
look  `$(document).ready(function()` and `id="specificationName' + specification_row + '"` are the same, but does'nt work.

element of table

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
  var specification_row = 3;

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#specificationName' + specification_row + '").tokenInput("http://....../products_specification_ajax.php" ,
        {
          tokenLimit: 1,
          resultsLimit: 5,
          onResult: function (results) {
            $.each(results, function (index, value) {
              value.name = value.id + " " + value.name;
            });
            return results;
          }
        });
  });


  function addSpecificationValue() {
   html  = '<tr id="specification-row' + specification_row + '">';

//specification_name
   html += '<td>';
   html += '  <input type="text" name="products_specification[' + specification_row + '][name]" value="" id="specificationName' + specification_row + '" class="form-control token-input" />';
   html += '  <input type="hidden" name="product_specification[' + specification_row + '][specification_id]" value="" />';
   html += '</td>';

//remove    
    html += '  <td class="text-md-right"><button type="button" onclick="$(\'#specification-row' + specification_row + '\').remove();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button></td>';
    html += '</tr>';

    $('#specification tbody').append(html);

    specification_row++;
}
```

my php code

```
      $content .= '<tr id="specification-row' . $t . '">';
        $content .= '  <td>' . HTML::inputField('products_specification[' . $t . '][name]', $specification_name, 'class="form-control token-input" id="specificationName' . $t . '"', null, null, null);
</td>';
          $content .= ' </tr>';
          $content .= '    </tbody>
                              <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                  <td colspan="5"></td>
                                  <td class="text-md-right"><button type="button" onclick="addSpecificationValue();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="' . $this->app->getDef('button_add') . '" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></button></td>                             
                                </tr>
                              </tfoot>
                            </table></td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                 ';



 $products_specification_ajax = OSCOM::link('products_specification_ajax.php');

          $output = <<<EOD
        <script type="text/javascript"><!--


          var specification_row = $t; // increment element 
// call token-input js for autocompletion : data list



            $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#specificationName' + specification_row + '").tokenInput("{$products_specification_ajax}" ,
                {
                  tokenLimit: 1,
                  resultsLimit: 5,
                  onResult: function (results) {
                    $.each(results, function (index, value) {
                      value.name = value.id + " " + value.name;
                    });
                    return results;
                  }
                });
          });

-- create new js row with all element

          function addSpecificationValue() {
           html  = '<tr id="specification-row' + specification_row + '">';

           html += '<td>';

-- input autocompketion call
           html += '  <input type="text" name="products_specification[' + specification_row + '][name]" value="" id="specificationName' + specification_row + '" class="form-control token-input" />';


           html += '  <input type="hidden" name="product_specification[' + specification_row + '][specification_id]" value="" />';
           html += '</td>';  
        //remove    
            html += '  <td class="text-md-right"><button type="button" onclick="$(\'#specification-row' + specification_row + '\').remove();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button></td>';
            html += '</tr>';

            $('#specification tbody').append(html);

            specification_row++;
        }
        </script>
    EOD;
```

Comment: Have you tried autocomplete plugin from JQuery UI?

Comment: no, my skills in js are not important